# Adding input value to localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently saving table row data to local storage using my AddToCart function like this:

So I have this table at the moment:

```
<table border="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th> Book Title </th>
   <th> Author </th>
   <th> Quantity </th>
   <th> Book </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="Book_Title">Gone </td>
  <td class="Author">Micheal Grant</td>
  <td class = "Quantity"><input></input></td>
  <th><button class="AddToCart">Add To Cart</button> </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="Book_Title">The Knife of never letting go</td>
  <td class="Author">Ryan Howard</td>
    <th class = "Quantity"><input></input></th>
  <td><button class="AddToCart">Add To Cart</button> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And this is what is in the AddToCart function:

```
$("table").on("click", ".AddToCart", function(e){

  // Get previous storage, if any.
  var storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
  if(storage==null){
  storage = [];
  }

  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var title = row.find("td").eq(0).text().trim();
  var author = row.find("td").eq(1).text().trim();
  var quantity = row.find("td").eq(2).text().trim();

  // Create an object to store.
  var data = {author:author,title:title,quantity:quantity};
  storage.push(data);

  // Store it.
  localStorage.setItem("cart",JSON.stringify(storage));

  });
```

The problem I am having at the moment is that when i try to save the input value for quantity it is not being saved in local storage it just comes up as "". Any fixes for this problem?

Comment: Note that inputs do not have closing tags, and you shouldn't have `th`s below the first `tr`.

Comment: Problem here is, you trying to grab the text from the `td` instead the value of the `input`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the quantity equal to `row.find("td").eq(2).text().trim()`, you'll want to set it to `row.find("input").val()`. This can be seen in the following working example:

```js
$("table").on("click", ".AddToCart", function(e) {

  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var title = row.find("td").eq(0).text().trim();
  var author = row.find("td").eq(1).text().trim();
  var quantity = row.find("input").val();

  // Create an object to store.
  var data = {
    author: author,
    title: title,
    quantity: quantity
  };

  console.log(data.quantity);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> Book Title </th>
      <th> Author </th>
      <th> Quantity </th>
      <th> Book </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Book_Title">Gone </td>
      <td class="Author">Micheal Grant</td>
      <td class="Quantity"><input></td>
      <td><button class="AddToCart">Add To Cart</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Book_Title">The Knife of never letting go</td>
      <td class="Author">Ryan Howard</td>
      <th class="Quantity"><input></th>
      <td><button class="AddToCart">Add To Cart</button> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also note that `<input>` is an **[empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element)** (so it does not have a closing tag), and `<tbody>` **[does not permit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody)** any `<th>` children. I've fixed up both of these in my answer.